# Can't find QuickOSM plugin in Qgis

Tags: qgis, quickosm

I installed Qgis 2.16.1 and QuickOSM. Then I activated the plugin and restarted Qgis. But the plugin does not appear under the Web tab.

Answer (score 3):

It comes under the **Vector** menu:

[image]

Comment: @user83045 - Most welcome =)