# Cannot find QuickOSM plugin in QGIS 3.28

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, openstreetmap, nominatim, quickosm

I have the same issue as described in this quesion: [Can't find QuickOSM plugin in Qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/211609/cant-find-quickosm-plugin-in-qgis), but in a newer version (3.28). The top bar of my QGIS looks like this:

[image]

The [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/211612/191643) to the previously asked question says I should look for the QuickOSM plugin in the Vector tab, but that does not work:

[image]

My Plugins tab:

[image]

QuickOSM is indeed installed:

[image]

My QGIS specification:

[image]

**How can I open the QuickOSM plugin in QGIS 3.28?**

Comment: In your snapshot the QuickOSM plugin is not checked in the box.  It does need to be checked to be available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin is indeed installed, but not enabled.

[image: Enable a plugin]